# How to start Erlang shell from inside Vim

Tags: vim, erlang

I want to use Vim as the editor for my Erlang coding.
I managed to install the plugin for Erlang in vim, and I want to know if it is possible to
compile the current buffer inside vim? In Emacs for example you can start Erlang shell using Ctrl C + Ctrl L
key combination. So is there a alternative in Vim to start the Erlang shell and then compile the current buffer?

Comment: I am using this plugin:[vimerl](https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl)

Comment: Just use `:!erl %` - it's a standard vim way to run shell commands.

Comment: Oh, automatic compilation. I use [sync](https://github.com/rustyio/sync.git), which does all the messy stuff from outside the editor.

Answer (score 5):

For a quick shell command from inside Vim, use `:!command -a -b arg1` (e.g. `:!ls -l`, `:!erl %`).

But Emacs is not Vim, they have different ideas behind both. Vim is just a text editor with programming extensions, it's not a place for terminal inside (just as for tetris and `M-x doctor`).

Vim maintainers refuse to add a full-blown terminal implementation into Vim itself (for more details, see `:help shell-window` ).

If you still want an in-buffer shell, you can take a look at [ConqueTerm](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) , but it does not work seamlessly. I tried it, but prefer using `tmux` / `screen` to split my console's screen estate into windows.

Comment: This means that every time i need to compile my code i should switch to the shell and then back to the Vim for editing? Is not it possible to have both in the same place for example using two different windows inside Vim?

Comment: @AKh_Sw it is possible to have both in windows of tmux/screen, but not in default Vim configuration.

Comment: Ahhh, disappointing! Maybe it is better if I try to find a solution to enhance Emacs graphic performance over the net.

Comment: If your issue is graphic performance of Emacs over the net, you could maybe try it in a non graphical mode with "emacs -nw"

Answer (score 0):

I also use the same [vimerl](https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl) plugin for erlang development in vim. However, I had to make a [small change](https://github.com/sanmiguel/vimerl/commit/e2b720026d1294eb2467e91556c35f9dd815e03e) to it to make some improvements to the way it compiles for checking.

Once I'd made these changes, writing the file (e.g. with `:w`) caused vimerl to compile that source file and put the warnings/errors in the [quickfix list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3acopen) (exactly the same way that `:make` would do if you had a Makefile in place).

FWIW, I also have the following configuration in my [vimrc](https://bitbucket.org/sanmiguel/dotfiles/src/a2183041c36e1a4cc2389d6454b6884432946e12/vim/vimrc.symlink?at=master#cl-222):

```
let g:erlangHighlightErrors = 1
let g:erlangHighlightBif = 1
let g:erlangCompletionDisplayDoc = 1
let g:erlangWranglerPath = "/usr/local/share/wrangler"
let g:erlangRefactoring = 1
```